# Python regex to match text in single quotes, ignoring escaped quotes (and tabs/newlines)

Tags: python, regex

Given a file of text, where the character I want to match are delimited by single-quotes, but might have zero or one escaped single-quote, as well as zero or more tabs and newline characters (not escaped) - I want to match the text only. Example:

```
menu_item = 'casserole';
menu_item = 'meat 
            loaf';
menu_item = 'Tony\'s magic pizza';
menu_item = 'hamburger';
menu_item = 'Dave\'s famous pizza';
menu_item = 'Dave\'s lesser-known
    gyro';
```

I want to grab only the text (and spaces), ignoring the tabs/newlines - and I don't actually care if the escaped quote appears in the results, as long as it doesn't affect the match:

```
casserole
meat loaf
Tonys magic pizza
hamburger
Daves famous pizza
Dave\'s lesser-known gyro # quote is okay if necessary.
```

I have manage to create a regex that *almost* does it - it handles the escaped quotes, but not the newlines:

```
menuPat = r"menu_item = \'(.*)(\\\')?(\t|\n)*(.*)\'"
for line in inFP.readlines():
    m = re.search(menuPat, line)
    if m is not None:
        print m.group()
```

There are definitely a ton of regular expression questions out there - but most are using Perl, and if there's one that does what I want, I couldn't figure it out :) And since I'm using Python, I don't care if it is spread across multiple groups, it's easy to recombine them.

Some Answers have said to just go with code for parsing the text. While I'm sure I *could* do that - I'm so *close* to having a working regex :) And it seems like it *should* be doable.

Update: I just realized that I am doing a Python *readlines()* to get each line, which obviously is breaking up the lines getting passed to the regex. I'm looking at re-writing it, but any suggestions on that part would also be very helpful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex for managing escaped characters for items like string literals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/430759/regex-for-managing-escaped-characters-for-items-like-string-literals)

Comment: Not that duplicated - I'm trying to handle (non-escaped) newlines breaking up my input data, also.

Comment: I agree, but I figured it was worth pointing out anyway. Just use `re.MULTILINE` (http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE) to match multiple lines, `$` to ignore/match endlines, and `\s` (same link) to match newspace. Go forth, grasshopper ;)

Comment: As a side note: the string `menu_item = 'Dave\'s lesser-known \n gyro';` doesn't contain an escaped single quote. The string literal contains one, but that's to help Python distinguish it from the end-of-string-literal quote. If you want actual testcases with escaped single quotes, you'd need something like `ohai = 'Dave\\\'s'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
menu_item = '((?:[^'\\]|\\')*)'
```

Here the `(?:[^'\\]|\\')*` part matches any sequence of any character except `'` and `\` or a literal `\'`. The former expression `[^'\\]` does also allow line breaks and tabulators that you then need to replace by a single space.

Comment: When you say, "replace by a single space" - do you mean cleanup/remove the tabs/line breaks *before* running this RE? When I tried your RE, it didn't match any of the lines with breaks.

Comment: @John C: No, I would do it afterwards with something like `re.sub(r"[\n\r\t]+", " ", match)`.

Comment: However, my match variable *m*, is empty for the input lines that have line breaks, so there's nothing to substitute.

Comment: Arg! Looking at my code, I'm doing a *readlines()* on the input file - which I presume is breaking on the newlines. Apparently I need to re-write more of my code (sigh).

Comment: It's worth noting that while this expression works for escaped quotes it will also *not* work when it encounters another escape sequence like `\n` or a lone backslash. You'll need to add all of the escape sequences you expect to encounter to the group, ie: `'((?:[^'\\]|\\|\\r|\\n|\\t|\\\\')*)'`

Answer (score 14):

This tested script should do the trick:

```py
import re
re_sq_long = r"""
    # Match single quoted string with escaped stuff.
    '            # Opening literal quote
    (            # $1: Capture string contents
      [^'\\]*    # Zero or more non-', non-backslash
      (?:        # "unroll-the-loop"!
        \\.      # Allow escaped anything.
        [^'\\]*  # Zero or more non-', non-backslash
      )*         # Finish {(special normal*)*} construct.
    )            # End $1: String contents.
    '            # Closing literal quote
    """
re_sq_short = r"'([^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*)'"

data = r'''
        menu_item = 'casserole';
        menu_item = 'meat 
                    loaf';
        menu_item = 'Tony\'s magic pizza';
        menu_item = 'hamburger';
        menu_item = 'Dave\'s famous pizza';
        menu_item = 'Dave\'s lesser-known
            gyro';'''
matches = re.findall(re_sq_long, data, re.DOTALL | re.VERBOSE)
menu_items = []
for match in matches:
    match = re.sub('\s+', ' ', match) # Clean whitespace
    match = re.sub(r'\\', '', match)  # remove escapes
    menu_items.append(match)          # Add to menu list

print (menu_items)
```

Here is the short version of the regex:

`'([^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*)'`

This regex is optimized using Jeffrey Friedl's *"unrolling-the-loop"* efficiency technique. (See: [Mastering Regular Expressions (3rd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596528124)) for details.

Note that the above regex is equivalent to the following one (which is more commonly seen but is much slower on most NFA regex implementations):

`'((?:[^'\\]|\\.)*)'`

Answer (score 2):

You cold try it like this:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"menu_item = '(.*?)(?<!\\)'", re.DOTALL)
```

It will start matching at the first single quote it finds and it ends at the first single quote not preceded by a backslash. It also captures any newlines and tabs found between the two single quotes.

Comment: Looks interesting, but as I noted in another comment - I just realized I am doing a *readlines()*, which is breaking on newlines, so I have another problem to fix.