# Parsing single or double quotes and allow for escaped characters using regular expressions (in Python)

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I have input that looks like a list of arguments:

```
input1 = '''
title="My First Blog" author='John Doe'
'''
```

The values can be surrounded by single or double quotes, however, escaping is also allowed:

```
input2 = '''
title='John\'s First Blog' author="John Doe"
'''
```

Is there a way to use regular expressions to extract the key value pairs accounting for either single or double quotes and escaped quotes?

Using python, I can use the following regular expression and handle the non-escaped quotes:

```
rex = r"(\w+)\=(?P<quote>['\"])(.*?)(?P=quote)"
```

The returns are then:

```
import re
re.findall(rex, input1)
[('title', '"', 'My First Blog'), ('author', "'", 'John Doe')]
```

and

```
import re
re.findall(rex, input2)
[('title', "'", 'John'), ('author', '"', 'John Doe')]
```

The latter being incorrect. I can't figure out how to handle escaped quotes--assumedly in the (.*?) section. I've been working with the solution in the posted answers on [Python regex to match text in single quotes, ignoring escaped quotes (and tabs/newlines)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452655/python-regex-to-match-text-in-single-quotes-ignoring-escaped-quotes-and-tabs-n) to no avail.

Technically, I don't need findall to return the quote character--rather just the key/value pairs--but that is easily dealt with.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT**

My inital regex solution had a bug in it. That bug masked an error in your input string: `input2` is not what you think it is:

```
>>> input2 = '''
... title='John\'s First Blog' author="John Doe"
... '''
>>> input2      # See - the apostrophe is not correctly escaped!
'\ntitle=\'John\'s First Blog\' author="John Doe"\n'
```

You need to make `input2` a raw string (or use double backslashes):

```
>>> input2 = r'''
... title='John\'s First Blog' author="John Doe"
... '''
>>> input2
'\ntitle=\'John\\\'s First Blog\' author="John Doe"\n'
```

Now you can use a regex that handles escaped quotes correctly:

```
>>> rex = re.compile(
    r"""(\w+)# Match an identifier (group 1)
    =        # Match =
    (['"])   # Match an opening quote (group 2)
    (        # Match and capture into group 3:
     (?:     # the following regex:
      \\.    # Either an escaped character
     |       # or
      (?!\2) # (as long as we're not right at the matching quote)
      .      # any other character.
     )*      # Repeat as needed
    )        # End of capturing group
    \2       # Match the corresponding closing quote.""", 
    re.DOTALL | re.VERBOSE)
>>> rex.findall(input2)
[('title', "'", "John\\'s First Blog"), ('author', '"', 'John Doe')]
```

Comment: Could you please explain the "or any other character" part? Doesn't having a `.` in an `or` make it always match?

Comment: @LevLevitsky: The dot matches any character, yes. But the previous lookahead assertion `(?!\2)` makes sure that it's not the closing quote, so in effect that dot will match any character but the closing quote.

Comment: @LevLevitsky: But you were absolutely right, there was a major error in my regex. Fixing it right now (the scope of the alternation was incorrect). Thanks for pointing me to it!

Comment: I can't take credit for that, really :) I haven't wrapped my mind around your regex yet. Somehow it seems to take me even longer when they're verbose...

Comment: @LevLevitsky: My corrected regex suddenly gave the wrong result. Puzzled, I looked closer at the input string and found that the initial problem is that Jeff wasn't using a raw string - see my revised answer...

Answer (score 5):

I think Tim's use of backreferences overcomplicates the expression and (guessing here) also makes it slower. The standard approach (used in the owl book) is to match single- and double-quoted strings separately:

```
rx = r'''(?x)
    (\w+) = (
        ' (?: \\. | [^'] )* '
        |
        " (?: \\. | [^"] )* "
        |
        [^'"\s]+
    )
'''
```

Add a bit of postprocessing and you're fine:

```
input2 = r'''
title='John\'s First Blog' author="John Doe"
'''

data = {k:v.strip("\"\'").decode('string-escape') for k, v in re.findall(rx, input2)}
print data
# {'author': 'John Doe', 'title': "John's First Blog"}
```

As a bonus, this also matches unquoted attributes like `weight=150`.

Add: here's a cleaner way without regular expressions:

```
input2 = r'''
title='John\'s First Blog' author="John Doe"
'''

import shlex

lex = shlex.shlex(input2, posix=True)
lex.escapedquotes = '\"\''
lex.whitespace = ' \n\t='
for token in lex:
    print token

# title
# John's First Blog
# author
# John Doe
```