# Regex for matching Python multiline string with escaped characters

Tags: python, regex

I'm parsing Python source code, and I've got regular expressions for single and double quoted strings (obtained by reading ridgerunner's answer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452655/python-regex-to-match-text-in-single-quotes-ignoring-escaped-quotes-and-tabs-n)).

```
single_quote_re = "'([^'\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^'\\\\]*)*)'";

double_quote_re = '"([^"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^"\\\\]*)*)"';
```

I'm trying to handle Python multiline strings now (three double-quotes).

```
s = '"""string one\'s end isn\'t here; \\""" it\'s here """ """string two here"""'
# correct output for findall should be:
#     ['string one\'s end isn\'t here; \\""" it\'s here ','string two here']
```

I tried messing around with it a bit, but still it's not right.

```
multiline_string_re = '"""([^(""")\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^(""")\\\\]*)*)"""'
```

There's gotta be some way to say """ that isn't immediately preceded by a backslash (in other words, the first double-quote isn't escaped).

**EDIT:** I should be getting closer; I've tried the following:

```
r'(?<!\\)""".*(?<!\\)"""'
# Matches the entire string; not what I'm going for.

r'(?<!\\)"""[^((?<!\\)""")](?<!\\)"""'
# Matches that space between the two strings ('""" """') in the sample string s (see code above, prior to edit).

r'(?<!\\)"""([^((?<!\\)""")]*(?:\\.[^((?<!\\)""")]*)*)(?<!\\)"""'
# Same result as before, but with the triple quotes shaved off (' ').
# Note: I do indeed want the triple quotes excluded.
```

**UPDATE:** <strike>The solution, thanks to sln, appears to be """[^"\\]*(?:(?:\\.|"")[^"\\]*)*"""</strike>

```
multiline_string_re = '"""[^"\\\\]*(?:(?:\\\\.|"")[^"\\\\]*)*"""'
re.findall(multiline_string_re, s, re.DOTALL)
# Result:
# ['"""string one\'s end isn\'t here; \\""" it\'s here """', '"""string two here"""']
```

The updated solution, thanks again to sln:

```
multiline_single_re = "'''[^'\\\\]*(?:(?:\\\\.|'{1,2}(?!'))[^'\\\\]*)*'''"
multiline_double_re = '"""[^"\\\\]*(?:(?:\\\\.|"{1,2}(?!"))[^"\\\\]*)*"""'
```

Comment: '""" that isn't immediately preceded by a backslash': `(?<!\\)"""`

Comment: If its a Vebatim ala Dot net's @"", then there is no escape char \\. Ie. `"string \\"` -> `@"""string \\"""`. Thats the way it is in Dot-net. Is it different in python?

Comment: @sln: AFAIK, the verbatim format with python look like this `r'....'`

Comment: @sln Python multiline strings (""") recognize escape characters. e.g. print """line1  \n line2""".

Comment: In general to find an escaped character, something like this `(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*\\([\S\s])(?!\\)` in capt group 1.

Comment: @Brad T - If python is using the double quote as the escape delimeter it won't process the backslash, to parse it as a string. Or, it shouldn't anyway. So the \n's should not be literal newlines.

Comment: Actually, it should probably just be this `(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*\\([\S\s])`

Comment: @Brad T - Posted a solution, hope it works.

Comment: Again, `ast.literal_eval` is *made* to parse those kinds of things. Stop ruining your life with overcomplicated regexes that are bound to fail at some point. (for one, yours doesn't parse `'''foo bar'''`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a test case using a regex in Perl. If you are going to allow escape
anything as well as escaped double quote form "", just modify one of the
regex's you've sited to allow for the double, double quote.

The source string is removed of single quote escaping.

```
 use strict;
 use warnings;

 $/ = undef;

 my $str = <DATA>;

 while ($str =~ /"[^"\\]*(?:(?:\\.|"")[^"\\]*)*"/sg )
 {
  print "found $&\n";

 }

  __DATA__

  """string one's end isn't here; \""" it's here """ """string two here"""
```

Output >>

```
 found """string one's end isn't here; \""" it's here """
 found """string two here"""
```

Note that for validity and error processing, the regex will need to contain
pass-through constructs (alternation) that can be processed in the body of the while loop.
Example `/"[^"\\]*(?:(?:\\.|"")[^"\\]*)*"|(.)/sg`,
then
while(){
  // if matched group 1, and its not a whitespace = possible error
}

**Add** - In reply to comments.

After some research on python block [literals](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals),

it appears you have to handle not only escaped characters, but
up to 2 double quotes in the body. Ie. `"` or `""`

To change the regex is simple. Add a 1-2 quantifier and restrain it with a lookahead assertion.

Below is the raw and string'd regex parts that you can pick and choose from.
Tested in Perl, it works.
Good Luck!

```
 # Raw - 
 #   (?s:
 #   """[^"\\]*(?:(?:\\.|"{1,2}(?!"))[^"\\]*)*"""
 #   |
 #   '''[^'\\]*(?:(?:\\.|'{1,2}(?!'))[^'\\]*)*'''
 #   )
 # String'd -
 #   '(?s:'
 #   '"""[^"\\\]*(?:(?:\\\.|"{1,2}(?!"))[^"\\\]*)*"""'
 #   '|'
 #   "'''[^'\\\\]*(?:(?:\\\\.|'{1,2}(?!'))[^'\\\\]*)*'''"
 #   ')'


 (?s:                # Dot-All
      # double quote literal block
      """                 # """ block open
      [^"\\]*             # 0 - many non " nor \
      (?:                 # Grp start
           (?:
                \\ .                # Escape anything
             |                      # or
                "{1,2}              # 1 - 2 "
                (?! " )             # Not followed by a "
           )
           [^"\\]*             # 0 - many non " nor \
      )*                  # Grp end, 0 - many times
      """                 # """ block close

   |                      # OR, 

      # single quote literal block
      '''                 # ''' block open
      [^'\\]*             # 0 - many non ' nor \
      (?:                 # Grp start
           (?:
                \\ .                # Escape anything
             |                      # or
                '{1,2}              # 1 - 2 '
                (?! ' )             # Not followed by a '
           )
           [^'\\]*             # 0 - many non ' nor \
      )*                  # Grp end, 0 - many times
      '''                 # ''' block close
 )
```

Comment: Tested it in Python and so far it appears to do the trick.  Thanks a lot!  For reference for anyone wanting to use this regex in Python, it's "[^"\\\\]*(?:(?:\\\\.|"")[^"\\\\]*)*" (the beginning and ending quotes are a part of the expression).

Comment: Update: turns out it needs a small modification:  """[^"\\\\]*(?:(?:\\\\.|"")[^"\\\\]*)*""".  As it was, it was also matching simple double quoted strings rather than the multiline version.

Comment: @Brad T - I added a modified regex in my post. I think you have to account for 1 or 2 quotes in the body of a literal block. Otherwise, `"""this is a "quote", end"""` will not pass the old regex. The modified one fixes this.

Comment: Thanks sln, tested them and working. I was also oblivious to triple single quotes being a valid variation, so that was a really nice catch as well.

Answer (score 1):

This snippet should match three quotes that have anything but a backslash before them.

```
[^\\]"""
```

You can integrate that into your regex.

Answer (score 1):

You can't parse Python source code with "simple" regexes.

The good news, however, is that the Python standard library comes with a full-fledged Python parser in the form of the `ast` module (http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html). Use that instead.

More specifically, the `literal_eval` function will parse literals (including all types of strings, and following escaping rules), and the `parse` function will parse arbitrary Python source code into an abstract syntax tree.

In addition, you should note that your example (s) actually parses to *one* string: `'string one\'s end isn\'t here; """ it\'s here string two here'`, because in Python, adjacent string literals are concatenated at parse-time, like so:

```
>>> "a" "b" "c"
"abc"
```

Comment: The only problem with this in my case is that the parser module I'm making is intended to work with many programming languages (e.g. Java, CSS, HTML, JavaScript, etc.).  It's not a pure regex solution.  With this is mind, I'm trying to tackle challenges like this one via regex and/or programming logic. The point is to break down every syntax component in the target source code so I can identify and work with each programmatically.  The ast module is Python only, unfortunately.

Comment: In this case, what you're writing is called a parser, it's not a simple collection of regexes, and it's certainly not language-agnostic: the languages you mentioned have very different grammars (Python's in in the `ast` docs, btw). Depending on what you want to do, there's a variety of existing libraries you want to use instead of rolling out your own: if all you're looking for is syntax highlighting, Pygments (http://pygments.org/) has you covered for more than a hundred languages. If you want more general-purpose parsing, take a look at Parsley (http://parsley.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Comment: Looking at the documentation, Parsley is exactly what I've been needing for my project as a whole.  Thanks a lot, man.  This'll definitely save me a huge amount of headaches and work.