# Example of "use \G in negative variable-length lookbehinds to limit how far back the lookbehind goes"

Tags: python, regex

In the pypi page of the awesome regex module (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) it is stated that \G can be used "in negative variable-length lookbehinds to limit how far back the lookbehind goes". Very interesting, but the page doesn't give any example and my white-belt regex-fu simply chokes when I try to imagine one.

Could anyone describe some sample use case?

Comment: I think it is meant to refer to `(?<!\G\w*)`, or something like this.

Comment: OK, ninja edited, but it is somewhat the same concept... I can't think of any use case for this, though.

Comment: I'm still wondering why the doc specifically says "negative lookbehind" though, rather than simply lookbehinds

Comment: `(?<!...)` negative lookbehind `(?<=..)` positive lookbehind. If there is a quantifier `?` or `*` or `+` present inside the lookehinds, then it's called variable length positive or negative lookbehind. `(?<!\G\w*)` called variable length negative lookbehind, because it has a quantifier `*`

Comment: It probably considers the complexity needed to get a "success" from a variable-length look-behind. For positive look-behind, it only need to go back as many characters for the pattern to match, while for negative look-behind, it needs to check to the beginning of the string. However, it baffles me, since the reverse would happen when we consider the failing case for the look-behind.

Comment: @sln to be honest, I was quite busy the last few days so I couldn't spend time on thinking of a solution/example to this question. Since the question "didn't reveive enough attention", I've put a bounty on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example that uses `\G` and a negative lookbehind creatively:

```
regex.match(r'\b\w+\b(?:\s(\w+\b)(?<!\G.*\b\1\b.*\b\1\b))*', words)
```

`words` should be a string of alphanumeric characters separated by a single whitespace, for example `"a b c d e a b b c d"`.

The pattern will match a sequence of unique words.

- `\w+` - Match the first word.
- `(?:\s(\w+\b) )*` - match additional words ...
- `(?<!\G.*\b\1\b.*\b\1\b)` - ... but for each new word added, check it didn't already appear until we get to `\G`.

A lookbehind at the end of the pattern that is limited at `\G` can assert another condition on the current match, which would not have been possible otherwise. Basically, the pattern is a variation on [using lookaheads for AND logic in regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/469913/7586), but is not limited to the whole string.

Here's a [working example](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cb%5Cw%2B%5Cb(%3F%3A%5Cs(%5Cw%2B%5Cb)(%3F%3C!%5CG.*%5Cb%5C1%5Cb.*%5Cb%5C1%5Cb))*&i=a%20b%20c%20d%20a%20e%20x%20x%20s%20aa%20a%20x%20x%20t%20i%20w&o=i) in .Net, which shares the same features.
Trying the same pattern in Python 2 with `findall` and the `regex` module gives me a segmentation fault, but `match` seems to work.

Comment: Doesn't crash for me (Python 3.4.1) but `findall` returns `['', '', '', '', '', '']` which doesn't seem useful.  `match` **does** return `<regex.Match object; span=(0, 9), match='a b c d e'>` which is neat!-)

Comment: I think the lookbehind using `\G` position works when its the first sub-expression. I don't see it as viable being the last one (on the right).

Comment: Yeah, you're right it only checks up to the current match position. I was confused a bit, thought it was open ended

Answer (score 3):

One example I could think of is using `\G` in a *positive* lookbehind to split a CSV row by commas:

```
regex.split(r'(?<=\G(?:"[^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*"|[^"]*)),', csv)
```

This is a variant you can only do with variable length lookbehind and `\G`.

Usually if you want to use `split` you add a lookahead until the end of the row, and check that the following records are all valid, like here [`,(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15739087/7586). This is somewhat annoying because you keep matching the end on the string over and over.

We also never explicitly mention that the unquoted values are not commas (`[^,]`) because we use `\G` to match since the previous comma.

Comment: Just a note. The split regex just validates the next comma is outside of dbl-quotes. I doesn't validate any evenness of the remaining quotes. The second regex (and link) is a really bad way of validation (as you say) since its like a N-factorial overhead. If validation is required, it could be done once per line, then use a normal field regex on it, avoid split altogether. Was benchmarked and discussed -> [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27450102/how-to-convert-comma-delimited-file-to-pipe-delimited-in-vb-net/27451004#27451004).

Comment: `[^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*` can be written as `(?:[^"]|"")*`. And depending on the engine, it can be made possessive.

Comment: @nhahtdh - You're right. I went with [unrolling-the-loop](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5455705/7586) without thinking about it too much. `(?:[^"]|"")*+` can work nicely here.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example that might be more useful than creative.
It uses a variable length negative lookbehind starting from the last match (`\G`)
checking forward to the current position.

In this case `(?<!\Ga+)b`, the result is that it matches every other `b` in a string where *b's* are separated by one or more `a`'s.

This can also be done in a fixed width lookbehind like `(?<!\Ga)b` where the result is that it matches every other `b` in a string where *b's* are separated by one `a`.

This is kind of a template where `a` and `b` could be bigger expressions and have a little more
meaning.

(*One thing to be aware of is that when using `\G` in a negative lookbehind, it is fairly easy to

satisfy the negative assertion. So, these kind of things have `gotcha` written all over it !!*)

Don't have Python (latest, beta?) to test this with, so below is using C# console app.

```
string strSrc = "abaabaabaabaabaab";
Regex rxGtest = new Regex(@"(?<!\Ga+)b");
Match _m = rxGtest.Match(strSrc);
while (_m.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Found: {0} at position {1}", _m.Groups[0].Value, _m.Index);
    _m = _m.NextMatch();
}
```

Output:

```
Found: b at position 4
Found: b at position 10
Found: b at position 16
```